# Empty user input exception c#

Tags: c#, exception, while-loop, user-input, string

The aim of this code is to repeat the question "Please enter your name" if the user does not input any data. However I am having trouble with making this work with the if statement.

```
while (true)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name:");
  string line = Console.ReadLine();

  if (line=String.empty) //I'm having difficulty making this a valid statement
    Console.WriteLine("Your entry was blank");
  else break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As looking your code, the error is in using making condition....You are using `assignment operator(=)` instead of `comparision operator(==)`......So do like this :

```
if (line == String.Empty)
{
       //Put your code
}
```

Or,You can simply do like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) 
           Console.WriteLine("Your entry was blank");
```

Or, you can use `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` as Oded answer specified but it is only available in `.NET 4` or above.....

Answer (score 4):

`line=String.empty` is an *assignment*, using the assignment (`=`) operator. It assigns `string.Empty` to `line`.

You should be using the *comparison* operator `==`.

Better yet, look at the `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` method (.NET 4.0+), or `string.IsNullOrEmpty`.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your if clause to `if(line == "")` and things should be just fine.

**=** is the assignment operator and you want to compare the values, therefore you should use the **==** comparison operator.